# How to replace PhpMyAdmin SQL table with local docker SQL table in PhpStorm

Tags: mysql, docker, phpmyadmin, phpstorm, local

I'm using [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) and am running a local [WordPress Docker](https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/) environment with persistent SQL database.

I can connect to my persistent SQL database using `localhost` fine.

[image]

Which I can the see all the tables in my local SQL WordPress database.

[image]

The problem I am having is getting my chosen table or tables into PhpMyadmin.

This is the context menu in PhpStorm when I right click on a database table.

[image]

Does anyone know how to do a direct replace like for selected tables.

For example I am just trying to replace `wp_gf_form` data with `wm_gf_form` data in PhpMyAdmin.

[image]

Any ideas would be great thanks.

Comment: "Dump Data to File" .. or export into SQL that uses "INSERT" commands on your source DB. Then just execute that resulting SQL file in your PhpMyadmin. That's the idea. https://postimg.cc/XBWqv7Ky

Comment: How to execute the insert in PhpMyAdmin? I've got the sql ready but i'm not quite sure how to get that data into the relative table in PhpMyAdmin

Comment: Try "Import" or "SQL" (if it's small size) tabs in phpMyAdmin (make a full DB backup first, of course). Truncate (empty) the table first if needed. Your export SQL (with INSERTS) may have that already -- check it before doing it. DEMO site: https://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/index.php?route=/server/import phpMyAdmin docs page: https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/import_export.html

Comment: That did the job in then end nicely. I just needed manually edit the table name in the phpstorm outputted sql insert file to match my table in phpadmin which are slightly different. Thanks